# Microsoft SQL Server Prepared statement within a for loop not working

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-update, prepared-statement

I need help with the following. I am trying in 2 ways. Both did not work. No rows updated. The same sql works without the loop (for a single string). But I want to execute the same sql for multiple strings.

Method1:

```
       PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

       String query = "UPDATE PeopleTable SET firstname = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(firstname as nvarchar(max)), ? ,'ReplacedFirstName') as ntext)";

       pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
       for(String s: myList) {

       pstmt.setString(1, s);

       pstmt.addBatch();

       }

       pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Method:2:

```
     PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

     String query = "UPDATE PeopleTable SET firstname = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(firstname as nvarchar(max)), ? ,'ReplacedFirstName') as ntext)";

     pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
     for(String s: myList) {

     pstmt.setString(1, s);

     pstmt.executeUpdate();
     stmt.clearParameters();

     }
```

Both are not working. Please help.

Comment: _"Both did not work."_  How?  Was there an exception message?  On what line? 
 An incorrect update?  No rows updated?  Please include specifics in your question.

Comment: No rows updated

Comment: Do you need to commit your statement?  I see a prepare statement but I think you need `conn.commit()` after your execute

Comment: First, as @sniperd said, you need to commit, after each executeUpdate. Lets see if it works first, there may be another issue you will encounter, for my own experience.